# Can some explain this bit of C++/C# magic?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm working on some code that is not mine, and it passes an argument in c++ to a (managed COM) c# method that doesn't have any parameters.  The code works fine, but I don't know why.

Can someone explain what's going on or point me to the c++ constructs that make it possible?

Here's the code:

```
//---------- C++ ----------
#import "wrapper.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only

BSTR b;
m_wrapper->getException(&b);
CW2A conv(b);
std::string s(conv);

if (! s.empty() ) {
    //Perform exception processing
{


//---------- C# Managed COM ----------
public class wrapper : Iwrapper 
{
    private exceptionStr = String.Empty;  // 'exceptionStr' set elsewhere in C# for an eventual pull by C++

    public string getException()
    {
        return exceptionStr;
    }

    //... other C# methods that may set 'exceptionStr'
}
```

Comment: What part are you asking about? Is it the BSTR to string?

Comment: The way C++ *uses* COM objects depends a lot on how it is configured in the `#import` line. In this case, the code example is using a variant that returns an `HRESULT` and the *return* is instead an *out* parameter. You could instead use a variant that returns a string but throws an exception on error.

Comment: Thanks @crashmstr and Felice Pollano, I won't pretend to completely understand, but I get the idea now and know what to research more.  I updated the post to include the import parameters in case someone is curious.

Comment: @Cork333 [MSDN #import Attributes (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/298h7faa.aspx) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COM` standard interface does not allow return parametres, since any function returns an `HRESULT`. So what appear to be as a return value in the COM object in C# is marshalled as a reference in the C++ side.